# How to handle No Data in pie chart?

Tags: amcharts

I am currently working with pie charts in amCharts plugin. Sometimes I had to face no data in pie chart. In this scenario, amCharts loads no graph.

How can I handle no data in pie chart? Is there any method to display inactive pie chart (disabled pie chart or something)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`AmCharts.addInitHandler`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCharts#addInitHandler) function to set custom function to call before chart is drawn. You can use it to check if `dataProvider` is empty and make all kinds of modifications to the chart.

I.e.:

```js
/**
 * amCharts Plugin: handle empty pie chart
 */
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {
  
  // check if data is mepty
  if (chart.dataProvider === undefined || chart.dataProvider.length === 0) {
    // add some bogus data
    var dp = {};
    dp[chart.titleField] = "";
    dp[chart.valueField] = 1;
    chart.dataProvider.push(dp)
    
    var dp = {};
    dp[chart.titleField] = "";
    dp[chart.valueField] = 1;
    chart.dataProvider.push(dp)
    
    var dp = {};
    dp[chart.titleField] = "";
    dp[chart.valueField] = 1;
    chart.dataProvider.push(dp)
    
    // disable slice labels and balloons
    chart.labelsEnabled = false;
    chart.balloonText = "";
    
    // add label to let users know the chart is empty
    chart.addLabel("50%", "50%", "The chart contains no data", "middle", 15);
    
    // dim the whole chart
    chart.alpha = 0.3;
  }
  
}, ["pie"]);

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [],
  "valueField": "value",
  "titleField": "title"
});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you martynasma for your great answer. you saved my time !

Comment: You're welcome. Just added a line that also disables rollover balloons. (didn't think of it before)